# Finiteness of automorphism group of finite map $f: C \to \mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a connected curve of arithmetic genus $g$
over algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero having only nodes
as singularities together with finite morphism
$f: C \to \mathbb{P}^1$.

In [3264 and All That](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/3264-and-all-that/DC062983CC5F8B7CDD37CFEBCCA5FEA4) by Eisenbud and Harris is claimed on page 313 that the the
automorphism group of the map $f$ — that is, automorphisms $\phi$ of $C$ such that
$f \circ \phi =f$ — is finite.

**Q1**: Why and how to prove it? If $C$ is smooth, then it follows immediately
from Hurwitz's automorphisms theorem. Clearly it suffice to check
that for every $q \in f^{-1}(p)$ the stabilizer of $q$ is finite. Why is
it true?

**Q2**: Is the automorphism group of $f$ also finite if we weaken the assumptions
on base field $k$? For example if we allow positive cahracteristic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: since maps of curves are determined by their action on the function field, we get an injection $\mathrm{Aut}(C/\mathbb{P}^1) \to \mathrm{Aut}(k(C)/k(t))$ but the latter is just a Galois group (or automorphism group of a field extension if you don't like this terminology for a non-Galois extension) of a finite extension of fields and hence is finite.

In particular, this shows that $|\mathrm{Aut}(C/\mathbb{P}^1)| \le \deg{f}$ where equality is achieved for so-called Galois covers (since for $C$ smooth it is equivalent to $k(C) / k(\mathbb{P}^1)$ Galois). This argument does not depend on the base curve being $\mathbb{P}^1$, just that you have a nonconstant map of (possibly singular) curves.

Q2: the above proof works over any field.

Comment: Let me add how in detail the maps of curves are determined by their action on the function field, and that's because: Say $\phi: C \to D$ is such morphism. If $C, D$ regular, then we have equivalence of categories between smooth curves and their function fields. If only $C$ regular - therefore normal - then $\phi$ factors uniquely through normalization  $\overline{D}$ of $D$ - which is smooth - and we are in previous case. And for $C,D$ arbitrary we precompose $\phi$ by normalization of $C$ and argue as before

Comment: More generally, any dominant map $f : X \to Y$ of varieties is determined by the corresponding map $k(Y) \to k(X)$. Indeed, if $f, g : X \to Y$ are two maps that agree on a dense subset then $f = g$ so we can pass to an affine open and then we reduce to: if $f,g : A \to B$ are injections of domains which are equal on the fraction fields then $f = g$.

Comment: The second statement holds even more generally, it is not neccessary to assumne $X,Y$ to be varieties; it suffice $X$ to be reduced and $Y$ separated over any base $S$, see eg Q. Liu's AG, Prop 3.3.11